# How to fix "Unescaped left brace in regex is illegal here in regex" error?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to configure a build that uses a Perl script that came made. I get this error while running the config script (Perl version v5.26.1)

```
Unescaped left brace in regex is illegal here in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^(.*)\$ENV{ <-- HERE (.*)}(.*)$/
```

The code in question is

```
if($text =~/^(.*)\$ENV{(.*)}(.*)$/){
            $text = $1.$ENV{$2}.$3;
        }
```

I am very new to Perl, Could anyone please help?TY

Answer (score 10):

Perl 5.26 introduced a change requiring literal braces to be escaped.  Here's the Perl changelog discussing it: https://perldoc.perl.org/5.26.0/perldelta.html

Presumably the script was written against an earlier version of Perl...

If the Perl script is still maintained somewhere I suggest either filing a bug or (better) publishing a PR to fix the issue.

If not, you could either fall back to an earlier version of Perl, or fix your local copy.

EDIT
Example of a fix:

```
if($text =~/^(.*)\$ENV\{(.*)\}(.*)$/){
        $text = $1.$ENV{$2}.$3;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question, you need to escape braces in the same way the `$` is escaped in your example - with a backslash, like so:

```
if ($string =~ /\{\}/) { ... }
```

Or they can be used inside brackets as a character class:

```
if ($string =~ /[{}]/) { ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

One possible reason to have this error for perl versions earlier than 5.33 (or 5.34) is using `{,n}` combinator. Earlier perl versions require it to be `{0,n}`.